# Aligning the label fields symfony

Tags: php, html, symfony-1.4

I'm using symfony 1.4 doctrine. Is it possible to align the labels using symfony? I have here a format of a auto generated form and I get this format(assume this is a form and "============" is a text box because I cant upload pics.).

```
               Name of Employee:                     ================
                   Position:                         ================
                Name of Group:                       ================
           Reservation Date: (yyyy/mm/dd)            ================
              Start time schedule:                   ================
                Endtime schedule:                    ================
              Number of employee(s):                 ================
```

What you see above the labels are all centered. Now I want to know if its possible to display like this format.

```
               Name of Employee:                     ================
               Position:                             ================
               Name of Group:                        ================
               Reservation Date: (yyyy/mm/dd)        ================
               Start time schedule:                  ================
               Endtime schedule:                     ================
               Number of employee(s):                ================
```

I tried to used the css like this format label{text-align:left;}. I tried that format but it didn't work. By the way i"m using a flat html format through symfony. I just want to know if it's  possible to align those labels on a flat html format. Thanks who can answer =)

Comment: Can you include your html?  It could be something as simple as `label { text-align: left; }` in your css

Comment: Tried coding it thru css, doesn't work

Comment: Can you include your HTML then?

Comment: Perhaps the labels are inline (css default) and are inside a div with center alignment. Try changing div alignment or setting the label to `display:block; width: NNNpx`.

Answer (score 1):

Create specific CSS class in your CSS file, such as

```
.myLabel{
  text-align: left;
}
```

then in the `configure()` function of your

```
/lib/form/doctrine/myModelForm.class.php
```

put this

```
$this->sfWidgetFormSchema['my_model']->setAttribute('class', 'myLabel');
```

finally, if this is not working, check what CSS properties is your label element having and inheriting (with a code inspector like to one provided by chrome and safari for instance)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a CSS Problem, as the label elements inherit a `text-align:center` from either a parent element or from `<html>` itself. Adding CSS `text-align:left` to `<label>` should fix it.